# How can I change the fan speed of my Nvidia 1050ti below 35% in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, fan

The question says it all really, I have Ubuntu 20.04, Nvidia driver version 470.82.00 and an MSI 1050ti Aero on an MSI B450 mobo.  All works as expected but on idle the 1050ti card is quite loud despite temps <33 degrees.  There is a setting in the Nvidia X Server settings to check enable GPU fan settings which I ticked and it enables a slider.  The slider starts at 35 (I think percent) and increasing does make the fan speed increase.  Unfortunately the reverse is not true and whilst I can select 0 - 34 it has absolutely no affect on the speed of the fan.

It's actually pretty noisy and when not gaming I'd really like it as near to silent as possible.

Is there anything I can do software wise or do I have to cut the fan :-)

[image]

Comment: 35% might be the minimum value the fan control accepts. You may play around with the "PowerMizer" settings too. I found that when setting it to "Prefer maximum performance" instead of "Adaptive" the fan seems to not spin up and down anymore when on the desktop, at the cost of slightly higher GPU temp and power consumption. And contrary to intuition, it seems the fan on my 1050Ti Aero is quieter when in max. performance mode (Level 2).

Comment: Thank you, that’s really helpful. I’ll take a look.